# Adding a ChildViewController causes strange behavior to the child viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, childviewcontroller

By "strange", I am noticing the following behavior:

- background color set by the `ChildViewController` does not appear
- despite adding a basic tap gesture recognizer to the `ChildViewController`, there is no tap recognition
- adding a `UIButton` to the ChildViewController results in the `UIButton` shown, but there is no response when tapping on the UIButton part

In my `ParentViewController`, I present the `ChildViewController` very generically, like so:

```
UIViewController *viewController;
viewController = (ChildViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildViewController"];

[self addChildViewController:viewController];

viewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
viewController.view.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:viewController.view];

[viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

And here are some very basic things I do in `ChildViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
UIButton *tapButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[tapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnTap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//button view customization code omitted for brevity 
tapButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
tapButton.enabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:tapButton];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnView)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

I ensured that everything is hooked up correctly - however, there is no acknowledgment in `tappedOnView` and `tappedOnTap` when I tap on it, in both simulator or device.

Am I missing something basic about presenting a `ChildViewController`?

**Edit**

For those curious, this very basic app is on [Github](https://github.com/zallanx/iMessageTestApp).

Comment: maybe try moving it out of `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear` and see what happens

Comment: strangely, moving it to `viewDidAppear` causes everything to disappear all together.

Comment: try to remove this line [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self]; and do this [self addChildViewController:viewController]; after [self.view addSubview:tapButton];

Comment: Thanks for the comment Kuntal. I commented out `didMoveToParentViewController:self`, but it didn't have any effect. Also, `[self addChildViewController:viewController` is called in the `ParentViewController`, while `[self.view addSubview:tapButton]` happens in `ChildViewController`, so I couldn't follow through on that suggestion.

Comment: In your `viewDidLoad` (and `viewDidAppear`, etc.), are you calling the `super` implementations?

Comment: @Rob Yep definitely. `[super viewWillAppear: animated]`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The containment calls are fine. But if you use the view debugger ([image: view debugger]), you'll see the `frame` is not correct. This is because you've turned off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, but you don't have any constraints. You can either turn that back on (and set `autoresizingMask` accordingly):

```
viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true;
```

Or you can define constraints rather than setting the `frame` (and redundantly setting the `center`):

```
//viewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
//viewController.view.center = self.view.center;

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [viewController.view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor],
    [viewController.view.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor],
    [viewController.view.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor],
    [viewController.view.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor]
]];
```

Comment: Wow, this simple thing did it. All of the previous issues have been solved as a result of setting this to `true`. Thanks for your insight on this, and for providing the code on setting the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ChildViewController *viewController;
viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildViewController"];

viewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleheight;

[self addChildViewController:viewController];
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
[viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

> Usually you don't need to do anything when adding a ViewController to another except those basic methods. since the views will be adjusted automatically and you don't need to set all those properties like size and center etc...